# Add MFSideMenu 3rd party library to swift project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm currently translating an Objective-C project I have over to Swift. In the process, I have a few implemented 3rd party libraries that are pure Objective-C like MFSideMenu and Parse.

I've created a Bridging-Header.h file per Apple's documentation and other's recommendations to bridge the Objective-C files with the Swift code. This works fine for frameworks like Parse. Unfortunately, when importing MFSideMenu and running the application, I receive the attached errors below.

[image: screen shot]

I was contemplating if this was because a library needed to be manually imported into the Objective-C files using it, so I attempted importing UIKit and Foundation in the project and manually added the frameworks without any success. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the compiler for swift no longer supports non modular based imports for frameworks. You must change all references to frameworks to @import statements rather #import.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, add code below at the header file of this class
`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`
it can help you